# Databinding bindinglist to combobox and removing items

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox, bindinglist

I am trying to use windows forms databinding to hook up a combobox to a ViewModel class.

```
var items = new BindingList<Person>();
comboBox.DataSource = items;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

All works ok except when I remove items from the list. For example if I remove the currently selected item (selected in the combobox) the selectedIndexChanged and SelectedValueChanged events of the combobox don't fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer. I had to use a BindingSource as middleman

```
  var bindingsSource = new BindingSource();
  bindingsSource.DataSource = new BindingList<Person>();
  comboBox1.DataSource = bindingsSource;
  comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This way I do get value changed events and even more than one when I deleted something.

Comment: Is this considered a Microsoft bug?  Is there any official write-up on it?