# ComboBox SelectedValueChanged not called when DataSource changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm surprised I hadn't noticed this before, and couldn't find this question anywhere. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. When I have the `DataSource` of a `ComboBox` set to a `BindingList`, and I remove an item from the list, the `SelectedValueChanged` or the `SelectedIndexChanged` events are not fired, but the SelectedValue does change. Here is the full source to reproduce:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public readonly BindingList<string> Items = new BindingList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add("One");
        Items.Add("Two");
        Items.Add("Three");
        comboBox1.DataSource = Items;

        comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        button1.Click += button1_Click;

        timer1.Interval = 250;
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private string GetCurrentText()
    {
        return comboBox1.SelectedValue as string ?? "NULL";
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "Index Changed: " + GetCurrentText() + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "Value Changed: " + GetCurrentText() + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = GetCurrentText();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Remove((string)comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

All the form has is a `ComboBox`, a `Button`, a `Timer` to keep track of the actual ComboBox's SelectedValue and a multiline `TextBox` to log the events.

To reproduce, run the form, select the second value ("Two") from the combo box and then press the button. No `SelectedValueChanged` nor `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be fired at the button press, but the form's text will show the new value ("Three") given by the timer, which will also be the value shown at the combo box. So the actual selected value will have certainly changed, with no event fired.

Unfortunately there's no `SelectedItemChanged` event so I don't know how are developers supposed to handle this situation. I'm not sure which other "edge" cases will cause the value to change silently so whatever hacky solution I come up with may not cover every case. I wonder if anyone has came up with a real solution.

Comment: All events work perfectly. Button event fired. I just copied and pasted your code.

Comment: Possible work-around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420273/databinding-bindinglist-to-combobox-and-removing-items

Comment: @TripleK Were you by any chance using anything other than .NET 4.5?

Comment: @TripleK I ment selected...changed events (just edited)

Comment: @TripleK I tried to edit my comment above to avoid spamming but was too late. I think you misunderstood and tested the buttonclick event instead of any of the combo box's selected...changed events. If so, sorry for the confusion, just edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

This is logically true. After you choose 'Two' ,`comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1`. Then you deleted 'Two' item. So 'Three' becomes index '1' from '2', no index changed occur in combo box. No combo's event will fire.

Your second time clicking button will fire combo's events.

Comment: Yes, but how about the SelectedValueChanged event?